# how can i make this java code more efficient

Tags: java

Don't be to critical because it my first ever working program
I want to know if its good and how I can make this more efficient in performance as well as memory consumption

here is my code:

```
package leren;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator3 {

static boolean again =true;
static Scanner keyIn = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String args[]){

        double in1, in2;
        char operator;

    while(again = true){
    System.out.println("Type your first number:");
    in1 = keyIn.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Type your second number:");
    in2 = keyIn.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Type your operator");
    operator = keyIn.next().charAt(0);

        switch(operator){
        case '+':
            System.out.println("your result is:"+(in1 + in2));
            Timer();
            again();
            break;

        case '-':
            System.out.println("your result is:"+(in1 - in2));
            Timer();
            again();
            break;

        case '/':
            System.out.println("your result is:"+(in1 / in2));
            Timer();
            again();
            break;

        case '*':
            System.out.println("your result is:"+(in1 * in2));
            Timer();
            again();
            break;

        }
    }
}
public static void Timer(){
    try{
        Thread.sleep(1500);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    }
}
public static void again(){

    char YoN;
    System.out.println("do you wanna do this again?[Y | N]");
    YoN = keyIn.next().charAt(0);
    switch(YoN){
    case 'Y':
        String[] args = {};
        Calculator3.main(args);
        break;
    case 'N':
        System.out.println("well get out of here");
        Timer();
        System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would help me to understand the things better.

Comment: Not your down-voter, but you may be posting on the wrong site as this might be better posted on code review. Regardless, you will need to be more specific by what you mean by "efficient" I think.

Comment: You don't use any loops or data structures, so efficiency is not relevant in this case...

Answer (score 2):

This version is not more memory efficient nor faster.

This version is easier for people to read and understand, including yourself after a few months.

I put most of the code into your class.  I got rid of the static methods, except for main.  I broke your code into methods.  I also fixed your while statement so you don't have to start the application over and over.

Here's the code.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator3 implements Runnable {

    private boolean again = true;
    private Scanner keyIn = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Calculator3().run();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (again) {
            double in1 = readDouble("Type your first number: ");
            double in2 = readDouble("Type your second number: ");
            char operator = readChar("Type your operator: ");
            System.out.println("Your result is: "
                    + operation(in1, in2, operator));
            timer();
            char yOrN = readChar("Do you want to do this again? [Y | N] ");
            if (Character.toLowerCase(yOrN) != 'y') {
                System.out.println("Well, get out of here");
                again = false;
            }
        }

        keyIn.close();
    }

    public double readDouble(String s) {
        System.out.print(s);
        return keyIn.nextDouble();
    }

    public char readChar(String s) {
        System.out.print(s);
        return keyIn.next().charAt(0);
    }

    public double operation(double in1, double in2, char operator) {
        switch (operator) {
        case '+':
            return in1 + in2;
        case '-':
            return in1 - in2;
        case '/':
            return in1 / in2;
        case '*':
            return in1 * in2;
        default:
            return 0D;
        }
    }

    public void timer() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very must this is something i can use and learn from. Can you maybe explain  little bits and pieces because I am a noob just started to code Java (14 years old). Something I think is difficult are: return stuff and to keep my code tidy can you help me with that.

Comment: @Youri: You can return nothing (void) or almost anything (char, int, double, String, String array, Object, Object array, etc).  In your program, we're dealing with char and double fields.  Whatever you say you're going to return (double), you must return (double).  The operation method is a good example of that.

Comment: @Youri: I use [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/) to code and format my Java.  Using an integrated development environment (IDE) helps you focus on the code and not the housekeeping, like formatting.

Comment: I also use Eclipse. I also think I need time to learn Java. I do this language only for 2 week or so I am happy with what I have learned so far. One last question if I need to know something can I send you a private message?

Comment: @Youri: Yes, you can message me through my [website](http://java-articles.info/articles/).  I should have said this before, but I was impressed with how you kept working on your code until it worked.  It will take a while to learn how to code, but the important thing to remember is that you're not coding for a machine.  You're coding so that other people (including yourself) can read and understand your code.

Comment: can you explain why you did `return 0D;` i dont understand that also why did you name in1/in2/operator readDouble and readChar. why is there a `keyIn.close`

Comment: @Youri: What do you want to return when the user types an invalid operator?  I chose 0.  I added a "D" to make the zero a double.  The readDouble method reads and returns a double.  The readChar method reads a String and returns the first character as a char.  The method names seem reasonable to me.  When you open a resource like System.in, you need to close the resource as well.  Eclipse should have given you a warning about a missing close.

Comment: O thx I know what you meaning I thought it wasn't nessecary